# Outlook read addin taking much time to load

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I have written a read addin for OWA which appears on the command ribbon just like any other addin (For e.g. Bing maps). But When I click on this addin button it takes much time to load. So the user sees the white blank screen for a long time and then the html part is rendered. Is there a possibility to display some sort of loading message before the final data is displayed?

[Blank screen after clicking the addin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxl90.png)

Comment: Do you see a blue spinner indicating that the iFrame is loading your add-in page (it might flash quickly)? Once the spinner disappears, your page has been loaded, and it's your responsibility to handle any further load times that your page may require, which includes displaying your own loading message.

Comment: Yes thanks. I think my service is responding very slow